# Why is the pointer location of shared memory across two blocks identical?

Tags: c++, pointers, cuda, gpu-shared-memory

I thought that shared memory of a cuda-device is private to a block. However, it seems to me that the pointer of shared memory across two blocks is identical:

```
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void foo() {
    __shared__ int ar[8];
    printf("shared memory pointer %p at blockidx %i\n", ar, blockIdx.x);
}

int main() {
    dim3 blockDim(1);
    dim3 gridDim(2);
    foo<<<gridDim, blockDim>>>();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
```

Running to code above produces:

```
shared memory pointer 0x7f88f5000000 at blockidx 0
shared memory pointer 0x7f88f5000000 at blockidx 1
```

With this program, I expected to create two different blocks, initialize shared memory on each block and obtain two different locations for the memory. Am I misunderstanding something? Or do these pointer indeed have a different physical location but within a block the addresses seem to be the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shared memory *is* block-private, i.e. threads from one block cannot access another block's shared memory.

... for this very reason, it's actually to be expected that the address range for shared memory will be *the same* for all blocks - but in each block, loading from or storing to these addresses affects the block-local shared memory.

For intuition: This is somewhat similar to how, on the CPU, code in two processes may use identical pointer addresses but they will actually access different physical locations in memory (usually).